# JavaScript Web Audio API and stopping samples

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

I'm trying to understand an aspect of JavaScript Web Audio API playing samples.
More specifically, I'm using Web Audio API to play a very short sample (actually a "click" sample, for a metronome).

This is what I do:

```
let sample = this.setupSample(this.audioContext, click1);
sample.start(time);
sample.stop(time + this.noteLength);
```

This piece of code is working if I run the app from desktop (my pc), but when I try to run the app from mobile, as soon as I click the "start" button to play the metronome, I get the following error:

> InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state.
>
> 93|   sample.stop(time + this.noteLength);

The first thing I tried was commenting that line:

```
let sample = this.setupSample(this.audioContext, click1);
sample.start(time);
// sample.stop(time + this.noteLength);
```

In this way, the app runs correctly both from desktop and mobile.

So, it seems to me that calling stop() on a sample that has already ended is not necessary, maybe even wrong.
Hence my question: is it wrong to call stop() on a sample already ended? Should I consider like it's implicitly called if the sample has stopped (ended) by itself? Plus, why I don't get that InvalidStateError error from desktop?

Thank you.

EDIT: to be more clear, here's what setupSample does:

```
setupSample = (audioContext, samplePath) => {
    const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    const myRequest = new Request(samplePath);

    fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
      return response.arrayBuffer();
      }).then(function(buffer) {
           audioContext.decodeAudioData(buffer, function(decodedData) {
             source.buffer = decodedData;
             source.connect(audioContext.destination);
           })
        })
     return source;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, `stop` is not a method defined in the Web Audio API. What does `setupSample` return?

Comment: It returns a source connected to the AudioContext destination. I've added the whole method definition in my question.

Comment: When is `time` assigned a value? Could it be possible that you're setting the stop time to be a time in the past? I always try to use `context.currentTime` instead of assigning it to a variable where I can.

OR

It could be that the buffer hasn't fully initialised with the data you're giving it. Therefore you're starting/stopping an incomplete buffer somehow.

Comment: `time` is a variable initially set at 0, then after each beat it's incremented by a value, `secondsPerBeat` (that is how many seconds each beat lasts).
So it shouldn't be a problem of setting the stop time in the past. Also, I did a test using an oscillator instead of a sample, and I didn't get the error on the `stop()`. 
Hence I think the error is calling a `stop()` on an already ended sample. Still, I can't figure out why I get the error only on mobile.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica, `stop` is inherited from the parent class `AudioScheduledSourceNode`. MDN states `Multiple calls to stop() are allowed.` but doesn't mention calling `stop` on a not-playing source